# php reading in strings from text area

Tags: php, string, textarea

```
$data = explode("\n", trim($_GET['names']));
while($i < count($data)) {
  if(!in_array($data[$i], $unique_names)){
    $unique_names[] = $names[$i];
   }
   $i = $i + 1;
 }
```

I am trying to accept only unique results from a textarea using this php code. It is not working because every string has an extra blank space, except for the last one.

I.E. 
"jeff "
"fred "
"bill "
"jeff"

so jeff will be added twice.

My question is:
How Do I get rid of that space?? I tried trim and it won't perform as intended.

Comment: You're not increasing `$i` in your for loop, so your code shouldn't even be terminating.

Comment: I am in my actual code. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to find unique values manually, you can use `array_unique()`. Secondly, `trim()` doesn't work on arrays.

Try:

```
$raw_names = explode("\n", $_GET['names']);
$trimmed_names = array_map('trim', $raw_names);
$unique_names = array_unique($trimmed_names);
```

Comment: I updated it to use trim on the array element, and it still doesn't perform as expected

Comment: Then you're still doing something wrong. Have you tried my code? Besides, you should never have a variable named `$data`. That isn't very descriptive.

Comment: The last update didn't work.. and I know... my actually code has descriptive variable names

Comment: Then there's something wrong elsewhere, Vlad. There's nothing wrong with my code. It'll be easier to track the bug if you post your actual code.

Comment: There's an extra empty cell

Comment: @sglessard: If there is an empty line, then yes, that'll be added, too.

Comment: I just got it. Thanks for your help!! the above code works, can you explain the array_map?? I don't understand that part

Comment: @Vlad [Read the manual on `array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map). It takes a function as the first argument and performs that on each element of the array.

Comment: @kba ok thanks for your help. Great answers. Appreciate the effort

Answer (score 0):

Use `trim(string)` to remove whitespace from the start and end. http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: You have to do the explode and THEN the trim.

Answer (score -1):

Inspired by [kba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/453331/kba) :

```
$data = explode("\n", trim($_GET['names']));
foreach ($data as &$e) {
    $e = trim($e);
}
$unique_names = array_unique($data);
```